# How to put data retrieved by XMLHttpRequest into an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to demonstrate the consequences of an XSS flaw to a client and to do so I need to retrieve a page, change some of the html in it with a simple search and replace, before finally displaying the data in an iframe. I have figured out the first two parts, but I'm struggling getting the iframe to work.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getSource()
{
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    var content=xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.write(content.replace(/MyString/gi, "StringtoReplace"));
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","indextest.html",true);
xmlhttp.send();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<body onload="getSource()">
</body>
</html>
```

How then would I put this into an iframe? I've been trying to put the document.write line into a variable and calling that as the iframe src but having no luck so far. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot

Comment: You may need to use two pages for this (one for the ajax fetch that puts that content in a div and another for the iframe to display the first page). You could also get away with doing the same thing in one page, but either way would require you to set the iframe src to the page that is doing the fetching and filling in the innerHTML of a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing by using document.write(), use this:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("YOUR IFRAME ID HERE");
iframe.contentDocument.write("HTML TAGS AND OTHER STUFF HERE");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Forgive my noobishness but I don't quite follow what should be in the iframe.contentDocument.write("here"); - do you mean this is where I should do the search and replace or?

Comment: Yah, that's where all the search and replace content would go IF its html. If its just plain text, put it in a html document within <p></p> tags.

Comment: Got it - thanks! I performed the search and replace earlier and assigned the edited code to a variable, which I then wrote with `iframe.document.write()` cheers